# Finding screen width of HD device with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, android, html, ios, css

I need to find the screen width of a device with JavaScript, I am unable to change the html and do not want to inject the meta viewport tag before doing so. Essentially I need to detect whether the device width is below 600px (in CSS pixels).

I have seen [various](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15876964/why-is-my-android-device-width-980px) [recommendations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6850164/get-the-device-width-in-javascript) but unfortunately I am getting different behaviour between iOS Safari and the default Android browser:

```
Command                                           iPhone4     GalaxyS3
------------------------------------------------------------------------
window.devicePixelRatio                           2           2      
window.innerWidth                                 982         626  
window.outerWidth                                 326         720
screen.width                                      320         720 
screen.availWidth                                 320         720  
matchMedia('(max-width: 599px)').matches          false       false
matchMedia('(max-device-width: 599px)').matches   true        false
```

Unfortunately the inconsistencies of the above values means I don't seem to be able to do it with JavaScript (e.g. I could divide screen.width by window.devicePixelRatio on Android, but this would then be incorrect on iOS).

Is there a reliable, cross browser way of doing this?

Answer (score 3):

You could try using [Verge](http://verge.airve.com/) viewport utility. It's an open source library. Then you could simply use:

```
$.viewportW() // Get the viewport width in pixels.
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: this seems to work, ideally I don't want to include an entire library for just one function but it's definitely an option.. thanks! I'll try read through the Verge source to see what they're doing

Comment: @penx You could try... document.documentElement.clientWidth